# How to save a dynamic object in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, dynamic, nhibernate-mapping

I have User table in database and I created Nhibernate mapping for fetching data from that table. I have created dynamic mapping that returns list of hashtables in response not the User type because there is no physical class exists for User. My code for fetching and saving data is as follows:

```
dynamic user = null;
using (ISession session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    user = session.CreateQuery("select u from User as u").List();

    user[0]["LastName"] = "s";
    session.Save(user[0]);
    session.Flush();
}

using (ISession otherSession = factory.OpenSession())
{
    user[0]["LastName"] = "ssss";
    otherSession.Save(user[0]);
    otherSession.Flush();
}
```

Now, in the first case when I fetch the data and save it in the same session, it works. But in the second case when I fetch the data in one session and then save the same object in another session it does not work. I get the error: "No persister for: System.Collections.Hashtable". I now that its a kind of weird requirement but if someone knows any way I can achieve it I will be thankful.

My nhibernate mapping for User table is as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns='urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' >
   <class entity-name='User' table='`User`'>
      <id name='UserId' column='`UserId`' type='string'>
        <generator class='identity'>
        </generator>
      </id>
      <property name='CreatedOn' column='`CreatedOn`'  type='DateTime' />
      <property name='FirstName' column='`FirstName`' type='string' />
      <property name='LastName' column='`LastName`' type='string' />
      <property name='LastUserNewResultAcknowledgedTime' column='`LastUserNewResultAcknowledgedTime`' type='string' />
      <property name='LoginName' column='`LoginName`' type='string' />
      <property name='LoginPassword' column='`LoginPassword`' type='string' />
      <property name='ModifiedBy' column='`ModifiedBy`' type='string'/>
      <property name='ModifiedOn' column='`ModifiedOn`' type='DateTime' />
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>"
```

Comment: It does not seems you are using dynamic since this is a regular class mapping. The error you report is probably due to forgotting "Embedded Resource" as a flag on the hbm file.

Comment: @FelicePollano, I would say that this is really the **dnymic model** mapping. while it seems to be the same as for classes (and in .hbm.xml file it is) it will be converted into dictionary not into `User` class (see my answer for a link)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are doing everything correctly. Mapping seems to be OK *(and that has been prooven in the first scenario)*. So your **dynamic model** is OK. see more here:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels

What could be missing *(it is not shown in your snippet)* is explicit switch to `dynamic-map`. It could be done in configuration of your factory or when you are getting a session with explicit parameter **EntityMode.Map**:

```
using (ISession otherSession = factory.OpenSession(EntityMode.Map))
{
 ...
}
```

Because if the session is expecting the POCO (that there is `User` class exists) and is provided with `Hashtable` (coming from previous session ,so now really detached object), it cannot find the persister for it.