# Generic Entity for NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to write a sort of generic data warehouse using NHibernate but I have run into a couple of issues.

I have a class defined as such:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Entity() { }
    public Entity (string schemaName) 
    {
        this.SchemaName = schemaName;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id {
        get { return this.Attributes.ContainsKey("id") ? (Guid)this.Attributes["id"] : Guid.Empty; }  
        set { this.Attributes ["id"] = value; }  
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

What i'd like to do is use the Attribute dictionary as the columns for a table and the SchemaName as the table name in SQL. I have a couple of wrapper functions to insert/retrieve/delete but it can only do ~170/second. I would like to improve this by using native NHibernate methods. I could technically generate a class in memory based on the column information and feed that to NHibernate but I don't think that is the best option.

How would I accomplish this? Is there an easier way to do this?

Currently I have something that generates the queries based on information passed in and then execute it by using CreateSqlQuery on the NHibernate session object.

Comment: How are you mapping this `Entity`?

Comment: It's not currently mapped, I was wondering if it's possible and how to do it. I am using raw SQL for the CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this question comes directly from NHibernates documentation, which I found in this post: [How to save a dynamic object in nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284923/how-to-save-a-dynamic-object-in-nhibernate)

The solution comes from Dynamic Models and in which you need to configure the session to handle this.

> Entity representation modes can also be set on a per ISession basis:

```
using (ISession dynamicSession = pocoSession.GetSession(EntityMode.Map))
{
    // Create a customer
    var frank = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    frank["name"] = "Frank";
    dynamicSession.Save("Customer", frank);
    ...
}
// Continue on pocoSession
```

The other alternative is to setup the session factory to do this for you; however, the documentation is unclear ... or I was too lazy to find it ... on how to achieve this.

Thank you @Radim Köhler for posting the documentation for this.

Comment: That is so nice to see you managed to get your answer. Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)